# MS - Access automatic scroll on list box.

Tags: ms-access, listbox, vba, ms-access-2016, autoscroll

I have created an access database form that displays a list of users and their productivity within a listbox. However when I get above 20 users, the list box cannot display the rest without scrolling.

Is there a way that I can make the listbox scroll automatically to the bottom and then reset to the top like the end credits in a movie played on an endless loop?

Answer (score 0):

To do what you appear to be asking I think you need to build your own scroller!
I would use these things to achieve that:

- a text box set to multi-line
- an array with each line of text to display in separate cells (or a recordset if you are brave)
- a timer function to update the text box
- a global counter to track the current first-line number of the text being displayed

Pseudocode:

```
Init:
    clear the text box
    load the array with the text & append each line to the text box as you go.
    set the pointer to 1

UpdateText (timer event):  
' get length of current string
    iLength = array(counter).text.length
    ' chop the first row off the text
    textbox.text  = right(textbox.text, len(textbox.text) - iLength)
    ' add the text back on to the end
    textbox.text.appendtext( array(counter).text)
    increment counter
    if counter > array-num-items, set counter to 1   ' scroll over
```

have fun!